# I have json data i need search `unique` if key exist or not

Tags: ruby

I have JSON data I need search `unique` if the key exists or not.

```
[
 {
  "key1" => []
 },
 {
  "key" => []
 }, 
 {
  "unique" => []
 }
]
```

I can use loop but need an efficient way to check `unique` exist or not

Comment: The only way to check if there is a hash with a certain key is to iterate through the whole array. It is not possible to do this faster with the data structure you defined. Why does it need to be this structure? Is it an option to change the format. for example, to have just one hash instead of multiple in an array?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to iterate through the array either way.

```
# You'll get found item or `nil`
data.find { |item| item.key?('unique') }

# You'll get `true` or `false`
data.any? { |item| item.key?('unique') }
```

Btw better to use a hash as an input instead of an array:

```
data = {
  "key1" => [],
  "key" => [],
  "unique" => []
 }

data.key?('unique')

=> true
```

Comment: You can use `any?` if you just want to know whether the key exists or not.